Content Type: Multipart/Form-Data
I have a spring boot application which is implemented from the spring cloud gateway starter mvc. When any api is hit with content type as multipart in its header, the request fails to fetch the query parameters
I tried removing the content type header from my request but somehow the server or browser or my react application is adding it again
I was expecting it to work fine when I remove the header explicitly

How are you submitting? Whoever is calling is submitting that content-type.
